# How to do countif in R based on dates

Tags: r, countif

I have this data in my excel files, and it has so much data to count if I do it in Excel. I want to count how many days in 1 month have a value of more than 50.

[image]

I'd like to turn it into something like :

[image]

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `count` with `as.yearmon` from `zoo` - `filter` the rows where 'Value' is greater than 50, then use `count` after converting to `yearmon` class with `as.yearmon`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
   filter(Value > 50) %>%
   count(month_year = as.yearmon(Date))
```

-ouptut

```
  month_year n
1   Jan 2010 3
2   Feb 2010 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14610, 14611, 14612, 14618, 
14618, 14624, 14641), class = "Date"), Value = c(27, 35, 78, 
88, 57, 48, 99)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is given by

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("1/1/2010", "1/2/2010", "1/3/2010", "1/9/2010", "1/9/2010", "1/15/2010", "2/1/2010"), "%m/%d/%Y"),
                 Value = c(27, 35, 78, 88, 57, 48, 99))
```

To count your specific values you could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(month_year = format(Date, "%m-%y")) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(Value > 50))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  month_year count
  <chr>      <int>
1 01-10          3
2 02-10          1
```

Note: Your `Date` column has to contain dates (as in `as.Date`).